# Call generic class function from outside

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am making a interface to 3th party database. I ran into basic class problem in C#. I can't get Generic class work in this case.

I have code like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Collection collection= new Collection();
        collection.Save();
    }
}

public class Collection : CollectionBase
{
    public DataTable<ItemA> itemA = new DataTable<ItemA>();
    public DataTable<ItemB> itemB = new DataTable<ItemB>();
}

public class CollectionBase
{ 
    public void Save()
    {
        var MyFields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var Field in MyFields)
        {
            if (Field.FieldType.IsGenericType && Field.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DataTable<>))
            {
                var ItemInstance = Field.GetValue(this);
                //ItemInstance.SaveAll(); //<--This is Missing
                var Item = ItemInstance as DataTable<BaseItem>; //<-- Returns null, debuger says this is DataTable<ItemA> (or ItemB at second loop)
                Item.SaveAll(); //<--(And fails for null exception, of cource)
            }
        }

    }
}

public class DataTable<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
    {
        //...
        return null;
    }
    public void SaveAll() { }
}

public class BaseItem
{}
public class ItemA : BaseItem
{}
public class ItemB : BaseItem 
{}
```

Field.GetValue(this) returns correct instance, but I can't find to way to call SaveAll function of DataTable<>.

Is this possible?

I know that I can work around this by make own Save function (this case) to Collection class, but I don't realy want to make this code like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataTable<T>` class is not covariant, so you cannot assign an object of type `DataTable<Derived>` to a variable of `DataTable<Base>`.

In fact, .NET doesn't support generic type variance in *classes* at all.

What you could do is create a covariant interface, using the `out` keyword:

```
IDataTable<out T>
{
    void SaveAll();
}
```

Then have your `DataTable<T>` implement it:

```
public class DataTable<T> : IDataTable<T>
```

Then you can do this:

```
var item = ItemInstance as IDataTable<BaseItem>;
item.SaveAll();
```

Further information: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).